# History of analysis?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, math-history

Any sites detailing the history of analysis post 1820 (to mid 1900s?) - vis-à-vis Cauchy, Weierstrass, Riemann, Bolzano, ..., Kuratowski, Hilbert?

It's something that appears quite interesting and I would like to have a knowledge of the direction analysis took and how things like topological spaces were motivated and viewed (pedagogically they're an extension of a metric space though I think there is much, much more to the history than this though I might be incorrect).

Being a poor student purchasing "mathematical analysis by its history" isn't an option (for two reasons; I need money for food and core material, but more importantly - mathematically the comments would be worthless as post 1900 detail is not included).

I looked to the library for history and - understandably - the books look at geometry, calculus (not analysis! Leibniz versus Newton) etc.

Comment: I think [Dieudonné](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jean_Dieudonné) wrote about the history of analysis, but I don't remember anything more specific than that.

Comment: Have you looked at a public or a college/university library? In the latter, you should find many such books. "A Radical Approach to Real Analysis" by Bressoud might be a good choice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many old books are available freely :
(Gutenberg)
[Smith(1906) 'History of Modern Mathematics'](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/8746)
[Rouse Ball(1908) 'A Short Account of the History of Mathematics'](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/31246)
(archive.org)
[Struik(1948) 'A concise history of mathematics'](http://www.archive.org/details/concisehistoryof00stru)
[Bell(1937) 'Men Of Mathematics'](http://www.archive.org/details/MenOfMathematics)
and so on...
Excellent reading!

Answer (score 4):

Try these books:

- [Analysis by Its History](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-0-387-94551-4) by Hairer and Wanner.
- [A History of Analysis](http://www.ams.org/bookstore-getitem/item=hmath-24) by Jahnke (ed).
- [A Radical Approach to Real Analysis](http://www.cambridge.org/gb/knowledge/isbn/item1176149/) by Bressoud.

Answer (score 3):

This is a general history, but it has a quite detailed overview of "analysis".  Morris Kline's *Mathematical Thought from Ancient to Modern Times* is very thorough, well written, and most importantly cheap.  It comes in three volumes in paperback. I believe you'd want volumes two and three.

Comment: +1 for what is probably the single best history of mathematics ever written. Well worth hunting down a copy of the 3-in-1 edition.

Answer (score 1):

The St Andrew's history of maths website may be a good starting point. This [link](http://www-groups.dcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~history/Indexes/Hist_Topics_alph.html) leads to the history topics index.